# How do I simplify transfer of Books to iPad

Tags: ipad, books

I upgraded to Maverics, and thought having iBooks on the Mac would be a good idea, so I could read epubs.

My books are gone from iTunes, although the process of adding them to a Collection in iBooks doesn't seem to be any better.

I only have selected Books on the iPad, and it seems I have to attach the iPad to iTunes, so I can select the Books in iBooks I want then sync.

On the iPad I then have to move the new books into the Category, as this doesn't seem to transfer in the sync.

This is an IMPROVEMENT?